How to check option for selected with Thymeleaf and Java Enum
With Spring and Thymeleaf, I'm doing the add and edit a user. I want to do an option check on a select tag on the user edit page. For example, if the user's role is ADMIN, if the admin option is not selected, let the user option be selected.
Spring Version: 3.2.2
Thymeleaf Version: 3.2.2
Thymeleaf Layout Dialect Version: 2.5.1
The model is as follows:
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    ...

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    ...
}

This is my enum file:
public enum Role {
    USER, ADMIN
}

This is my method in controller file:
Optional<User> validUser = userRepository.findById(id);
model.addAttribute("item", validUser.orElse(null));
model.addAttribute("editPost", editPost);
return "users/edit";

This is my editPostDto:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EditPost {
    ...
    private Role role;
    ...
}

This is my template file:
<form action="/users/edit" th:action="@{/users/edit}" method="post" th:object="${editPost}">

...

<select name="role" class="form-control" th:field="*{role}">
    <option value="ADMIN" th:selected="${item.role == 'ADMIN'}">Admin</option>
    <option value="USER" th:selected="${item.role == 'USER'}">User</option>
</select>

...

</form>

I tried a lot of solutions with chatgpt but I did not fix it. I tried these solutions but they are not work for me.
<select name="role" class="form-control" th:field="*{role}">
    <option value="ADMIN" th:selected="${item.role == T(com.emrtnm.example.Role).ADMIN}">Admin</option>
     <option value="USER" th:selected="${item.role == T(com.example.enums.Role).USER}">User</option>
</select>

Thanks for helping.

I did something similar but for companies. Try using this:
<select id="company" class="form-select" name="companyId">
    <option value="0" th:selected="${contact.companyId == null}">Kein Unternehmen</option>
    <option th:each="company, i : ${company}" th:value="${company.id}" th:text="${company.name}" th:selected="${contact.companyId != null and contact.companyId == company.id}"></option>
</select>

